# Why did my program crash when I tried the perror function?

Tags: c

I'm testing the perror function in C, and according to [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/perror/) it prints a default message when a null pointer is passed:

```
int main(void)
{
    int *p;
    perror(p); //crashes
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cause `int* p` contains a random/garbage value.

It is not an `NULL`pointer. You need to explicitly initialize it with `p = NULL;`.

Using an uninitialised variable is Undefined behaviour.

`main()` also needs to `return 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `p` isn't initialized to 0 automatically in C (this isn't Java).

```
int *p = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing an invalid pointer to `perror` is undefined behavior.

> (C99, 7.1.4p1) "Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow: If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding
>   parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a function
>   with variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: How do you find the reference source so fast? Thanks!

Comment: How about: `7.19.10.4-2`: *if `s` is not a null pointer and the character pointed to by `s` is not the null character*.

Comment: @cnicutar I would quote 4.p2 that says "Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words "undefined behavior" or by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior.".

Comment: Well you could be right. However the standard would usually make it clear "if so on so, the result is not defined". Why did they mention `s` not being NULL without any mention of UB ?

Comment: @cnicutar I also find the standard not clear in this case and your point is valid too.

Comment: @ouah, I think the standard implies, that in case `s` is null, it ignores it and just prints the error message, without any appending on the beginning of the error message. Which I think is not UB since the behaviour is implicitly specified.

Comment: @Muggen and cnicutar by re-reading the perror paragraph I think it is clear it is not UB, my mistake. Just the first sequence of character is ignored in case of a null argument.